# Determine the Dynkin systems and Sigma-fields in {1,2,3,4}

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I have checked both two definitions, but still confuse on how, exactly, solve it.

Here are definitions of these two conceptions from Lecture Notes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a small set you can do it by brute force.  Consider any sigma field or Dynkin system of {1,2,3,4}

We know it's got to have {} and {1,2,3,4} in it.

What other sets can it have? Some combination of:
$\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{1,3,4\}, \{1,2,4\}, \{2,3,4\}$

Start by choosing combinations of these subsets, then making a list of what else the Dynkin systems and Sigma fields are 'generated' by these combinations must contain. You will quickly see that there are far fewer Sigma fields and Dynkin systems than there are combinations that you can choose.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooo much!
for signa fields (S2), does that mean F and F(c) should all be in one prosible combination?
 {{},{1,2,3,4},{1},{2}} is not fit, isn't it?

Comment: No, you're right that it isn't fit. But the $\sigma$-field *generated* by $S=\{\ \{1,2,3,4\},\{\},\{1\},\{2\}\ \}$ is: $S \cup \{\ \{1,2\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{3,4\}\ \}$. (Inclusion of $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ forces inclusion of some other sets)

Comment: That also happens to be the Dynkin system generated by those sets

Comment: Thank you!I'll try it now.

Comment: by the way, is {{},{1,2,3,4},{1}{2,3,4}} a possible combination for sigma fields?

Comment: No problem! Yes it is a $\sigma$-field. It meets all of the criteria for one. (Closed under countable union, complement, contains the space)

Comment: so, for sigma fields, there are only 3+4=7 combinations?
4 for such as: {}+{all}+{1}+{2,3,4}
3 for such as: {}+{all}+{1,2}+{3,4}

Comment: en, I found the above was wrong. for such {{},{all},{1},{2},{2,3,4},{1,3,4}}, also fit,isn't it? for 1 combination, it is always contain even number of elements?

Comment: I count 15 sigma-fields: 1 of the form: $\{\Omega, \{\}\}$, 1 with all the subsets, 4 of the form: $\{\Omega, \{\}, \{1\}, \{2,3,4\} \}$ (depending on what singleton you throw in), 6 of the form: $\{\Omega, \{\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,3,4\}, \{2,3,4\}\}$ (depending on what 2 singletons you throw in), 3 of the form: $\{\Omega, \{\}, \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}\}$ (depending on what disjoint 2-pairings of 1,2,3,4 you throw in),

Comment: I count more than 15. what about form like {{},{all},{1},{2},{3},{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{1,2,4}}

Comment: @Vivian That last one in your comment would also need {4} as complement of {1,2,3}, so would wind up being the set of all subsets.

Comment: OOOOOO, I got it!!!! I' miss understanding S(3)!!!
Thanks soooooooo much for your kind and so0000rry for taking your time soooo loooooong!!!

Comment: @ enthdegree
is the number of Dynkin combinations more than sigma fields?